# From the View, how do I pass custom "choices" into a form's ChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

According to Django docs., the ChoiceField accepts [an iterable of two tuples, "or a callable that returns such an iterable"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) to use as choices for the field.

I've defined `ChoiceFields` within my forms:

```
class PairRequestForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=RadioSelect, required=False)
```

Here is the view where I'm attempting to pass a tuple of custom choices:

```
class PairRequestView(FormView):
    form_class = PairRequestForm

    def get_initial(self):
        requester_obj = Profile.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
        accepter_obj = Profile.objects.get(user__username=self.kwargs.get("username"))

        # `get_favorites()` is the object's method which returns a tuple.
        favorites_set = requester_obj.get_favorites()

        initial = super(PairRequestView, self).get_initial()

        initial['favorite_choices'] = favorites_set

        return initial
```

Within my `models.py`, here is the method used above that returns a tuple:

```
def get_favorites(self):
        return (('a', self.fave1), ('b', self.fave2), ('c', self.fave3))
```

From my understanding, if I want to pre-populate the form, I pass data in by overriding `get_initial()`. I attempt to set the initial data of the form's `favorite_choices` with a callable. The callable being `favorites_set`.

With the current code, I am given an error of `'tuple' object is not callable`

How can I pre-populate the RadioSelect ChoiceField with my own choices?

edit: I've also tried setting `initial['favorite_choices'].choices = favorites_set`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method is made to populate the initial value of the fields of your form. Not to set the available `choices` or to modify your fields attributes.

To successfully passing your choices from your view to the form, you need to implement the [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method in your view:

```
class PairRequestView(FormView):
    form_class = PairRequestForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Passing the `choices` from your view to the form __init__ method"""

        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()

        # Here you can pass additional kwargs arguments to the form.
        kwargs['favorite_choices'] = [('choice_value', 'choice_label')]

        return kwargs
```

And in your form, get the choices from the kwargs argument in the `__init__` method and set the choices on the field:

```
class PairRequestForm(forms.Form):

    favorite_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=RadioSelect, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Populating the choices of  the favorite_choices field using the favorites_choices kwargs"""

        favorites_choices = kwargs.pop('favorite_choices')

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['favorite_choices'].choices = favorites_choices
```

And voilà !

Comment: Is there a particular reason you put the `super().__init__()` call before editing `self.fields[].choices`?

Comment: If you dont' call the base `__init__` before, you will not have any `fields` attribute defined. The `fields` attribute is defined in the `BaseForm` init method here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L95

Answer (score 6):

Another simple way of doing this would be:

```
class PairRequestView(FormView):
    form_class = PairRequestForm

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
         requester_obj = Profile.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
         favorites_set = requester_obj.get_favorites()
         form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
         form.fields['favorite_choices'].choices = favorites_set
         return form
```

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate the choices in a proper parameter to the contructor of the form. Say you have a drop-down for 'groups' and you want to pass 'group choices':

```
class CreateAccountForm(forms.Form):

   def __init__(self, groupChoices_, *args, **kwargs):
      super(CreateAccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['group'].choices = groupChoices_

   group = forms.ChoiceField()
```

In your view, use groupChoices_ always as the 1st argument, e.g:

```
groupChoices = [
  (2, 'A'),
  (4, 'B'),
]
form = CreateAccountForm(groupChoices, request_.POST)
```

No need to worry about `kwargs` horribleness!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because OP uses FormView